# I have a filter in Angularjs and it returned "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my filter :

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('categoryFilter', [function () {
return function (clients, selectedCategory) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(clients) && !angular.isUndefined(selectedCategory) && selectedCategory.length > 0) {
        var tempClients = [];
        angular.forEach(selectedCategory, function (id) {
            angular.forEach(clients, function (client) {
                if (angular.equals(client.category.id, id)) {
                    tempClients.push(client);
                }
            });
        });
        return tempClients;
    } else {
        return clients;
    }
};
}]);
```

And in controller i have a function :

```
$scope.setSelectedClient = function () {
var id = this.category.id;
if (_.contains($scope.selectedCategory, id)) {
    $scope.selectedCategory = _.without($scope.selectedCategory, id);
} else {
    $scope.selectedCategory.push(id);
}
return false;
```

};

And the json :

```
[
{
   "id":"1",
   "name": "client1",
   "image":"images/client1.jpg",
   "category": {
       "id": "2",
       "designation": "Web"
    }
},
{
   "id":"2",
   "name": "client2",
   "image":"images/client2.jpg",
   "category": {
       "id":"1",
       "designation": "design"
    }
}]
```

The view :

```
<ul class="clients-images col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<li class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" data-ng-repeat="client in filtered = (clients | categoryFilter:selectedCategory) | offset: clientsPerPage*currentPage | limitTo: clientsPerPage">
   <a href="#projects/{{client.id}}"><img ng-src="{{client.image}}" width="210px" />
      <p>{{client.category.designation}}</p></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The error is on this line "if (angular.equals(client.category.id, id)) {". If i call {{client.category.id}} in my view it works perfectly.

Comment: could it be you're missing the "key" parameter in the foreach? sintax is angular.forEach(collection, function(value,key){...}

Comment: can you use console.log or debugging to check the value of client and client.category each iteration of the loop before the if statement?

Comment: Show the view to us, how is you calling the Filter?

Comment: While it's not very hard to read this code, please make it more readable by adding it to your post. And I agree with mer10z_tech. Try to write some information to the console using `console.log()`

Comment: If i write in console.log(client.category.id), it will show me the id's but at a time gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined”

Comment: Log `clients` and `selectedCategory` values instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful:

In Filter:

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('categoryFilter', [function () {
return function (clients, args) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(clients) && !angular.isUndefined(args.selectedCategory) && args.selectedCategory.length > 0) {
        var tempClients = [];
        angular.forEach(args.selectedCategory, function (id) {
            angular.forEach(clients, function (client) {
                if (angular.equals(client.category.id, id)) {
                    tempClients.push(client);
                }
            });
        });
        return tempClients;
    } else {
        return clients;
    }
};
}]);
```

In HTML:

```
<li class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" 
data-ng-repeat="client in clients 
| categoryFilter:{selectedCategory: selectedCategory} 
| offset: clientsPerPage*currentPage 
| limitTo: clientsPerPage">
```